# Unable to publish bot application from visual studio 2015

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio, botframework

I have developed bot application and trying to publish it on azure from the visual studio 2015. Although I have the subscription of Windows Azure and the Visual studio too. But despite of that I am unable to publish the application on the azure.
[image: Error while publishing bot on azure.]

When i see my azure app services the site is created there but application is not hosted on azure.
I'm unable to understand this issue.
How to resolve this issue?

Comment: I've the same error. I couldn't find a solution. But I installed VS2017 community and it works fine. I think there is an error with VS 2015 and Azure SDK.

Answer (score 1):

Is the 'Central US' the correct location? Is it already registered somewhere else?

[Here is an article on moving a resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-move-resources)

From the article:

"The destination subscription must be registered for the resource provider of the resource being moved. If not, you will receive an error stating that the subscription is not registered for a resource type. You might encounter this problem when moving a resource to a new subscription, but that subscription has never been used with that resource type. To learn how to check the registration status and register resource providers, see [Resource providers and types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-supported-services#resource-providers-and-types)."

Is it possible it is in a different zone?

Comment: But the thing is that when I am uploading the project form the visual studio 2013 I am anble to upload the project. But when i am trying to upload the project form the Visual studio 2015 It giving me the error which i have discussed in the post.

Comment: No it's not possible in any other zone as well if i am trying to upload the project from the visual studio 2015.